# How to return an int to float upto 2 zeros?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Expected output: 56.00 and my output: 56.0

```
from statistics import mean
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    student_marks = {}
    for _ in range(n):
        name, *line = input().split()
        scores = list(map(float, line))
        student_marks[name] = scores
    query_name = input()
    marks_list=list(student_marks[query_name])
    ans=(mean(marks_list))
    print(round(ans),2)
```

My answer is 56.0 for the input, so is there any short way to do this?

Comment: look this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/455634/5805827

Comment: I don't think thats possible if your are trying to work with them as floats since 52.0 and 52.00 is the exact same thing, so why would python add another 0? But you can still add extra 00 by converting your number into string and then adding 0s.

Comment: `print(f'{and:.2f}')`

Answer (score 2):

You can format your float like this:

```
>>> "{:.2f}".format(56.0)
'56.00'
```

or

```
>>> "%.2f" % 56.0
'56.00'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the line

```
print(round(ans),2)
```

to

```
print("{:.2f}".format(round(a, 2)))
```